# Check for name of a directory from an array

Tags: c#, arrays, directory, match

I'm working on a program that is supposed to scan a specific directory looking for any directories within it that have specific names, and if it finds them, tell the user.

Currently, the way I am loading the names its searching for is like this:

```
static string path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"database.txt");
static string[] database = File.ReadAllLines(datapath);
```

I am using this as an array of names to look for when looking through a specific directory. I am doing so with a foreach method.

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\ExampleDirectory");
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
        {

        }
```

Is there a way to see if any of the names in the file "database.txt" match any names of directories found within "C:\ExampleDirectory"?

The only way I can think of doing this is:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(versionspath);
        foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            if(dir.Name == //Something...) {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found!");
            break;}
        }
```

But this obviously won't work, and I cannot think of any other way to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `if (database.Contains(dir.Name)) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your other questions on stackoverflow, I presume your question is a homework or you are a passionate hobby programmer, am I right? So I'll try to explain the principle here continuing your almost complete solution.
You will need a nested loop here, a loop in a loop. In the outer loop you iterate through the directories. You already got this one. For each directory you need to loop through the names in `database` to see if any item in it matches the name of the directory:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(versionspath);
foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in di.GetDirectories())
{
    foreach (string name in database)
    {        
        if (dir.Name == name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match found!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your goal, you might want to exit at the first matching directory. The sample code above doesn't. The single `break;` statement only exits the inner loop, not the outer one. So it continues to check the next directory. Try to figure it out yourself how to stop at the first match (by exiting the outer loop).

Comment: Best answer i've gotten on stack lol. Yes, passionate hobbyist (with the hopes of being a student whenever I can gather the motivation and COVID wont kill me and everyone I love.) 
I think i have a solution for breaking out at the first match (which is what I should ideally do. Thought about that being the most optimal way of doing this earlier, rather than going through all matches), and while it may not be elegant it should hopefully work. Thank you so much <3

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Happy coding! ;)

Answer (score 1):

As usual, LINQ is the way to go. Whenever you have to find matches or not-matches between two lists and both lists containing different types, you'll have to use `.Join()` or `.GroupJoin()`.

The `.Join()` comes into play, if you need to find a 1:1 relationship and the `.GroupJoin()` for any kind of 1-to relationship (1:0, 1:many or also 1:1).

So, if you need the directories that match your list, this sounds for a job to the `.Join()` operator:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Where ever this comes normally from.
    string[] database = new[] { "fOo", "bAr" };
    string startDirectory = @"D:\baseFolder";

    // A method that returns an IEnumerable<string>
    // Using maybe a recursive approach to get all directories and/or files
    var candidates = LoadCandidates(startDirectory);

    var matches = database.Join(
        candidates,
        // Simply pick the database entry as is.
        dbEntry => dbEntry,
        // Only take the last portion of the given path.
        fullPath => Path.GetFileName(fullPath),
        // Return only the full path from the given matching pair.
        (dbEntry, fullPath) => fullPath,
        // Ignore case on comparison.
        StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    foreach (var match in matches)
    {
        // Shows "D:\baseFolder\foo"
        Console.WriteLine(match);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> LoadCandidates(string baseFolder)
{
    return new[] { @"D:\baseFolder\foo", @"D:\basefolder\baz" };
    //return Directory.EnumerateDirectories(baseFolder, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to do this

```
var allDirectoryNames = di.GetDirectories().Select(d => d.Name);
var matches = allDirectoryNames.Intersect(database);

if (matches.Any())
    Console.WriteLine("Matches found!");
```

In the first line we get all the directory names, then we use the `Intersect()` method to see which ones are present in both `allDirectoryNames` and `database`